# What has changed since "Javascript The Good Parts"?

Tags: javascript, language-features

I've finally just finished reading the above book, and noticed it was published in '08.  There were many statements of things like "this should be dropped from the language", and I'm wondering if any of the recommendations were followed since then.  Have any of the opinions in the book been officially dismissed or taken action upon by the Ecmascript/Javascript designers/implementers in these last 6 years?  What parts of the book have been made irrelevant or more important by new developments in JS?

Comment: Could you quote these "should be dropped from the language" statements? Not all of us have the book, and it would make your question a little less broad.

Comment: I think this is a great question. I hope it doesn't get closed as too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: `strict` mode has happened since then which attempts to clean up some of the bad aspects of Javascript.

Comment: @NPE It is a good question, and I usually love these kind of questions, but I think it'll fall under the "too broad or opinion-based". I feel that SO is more for : "why is this not working" or "why is this code broken" these days ... maybe they should open a new StackExchange site for questions like this?

Answer (score 3):

### This will be huge to be answered here.

*But here they are:*

1. `"use strict"` or [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) was introduced
2. [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set) operators now allows the identifier to be numeric or a string
3. [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can accept any array-like object as the arguments list, instead of only true arrays
4. Trailing commas are no longer accepted in [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON)
5. Global objects [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) made read-only as part of ECMA5 specification
6. ISO 8601 format support in [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
7. 12 new functions added to [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) object.
8. [`Date.toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) was added.
9. [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) was added.
10. [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) was added.
11. [`Array.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)  now works even on non-arrays by either returning the result of calling its `join()` method if one is available or by calling its `toString()` method.
12. [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) was introduced in Javascript 1.8
13. [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) added, which returns the prototype of the specified object.
14. [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object was introduced which offers support for creating Object and Function proxies that enable meta-programming in JavaScript.
15. [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) now has [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), [`trimLeft()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimLeft), [`trimRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimRight) and [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) methods.

Apart from these, some of syntax changes have been happened.

### Update:

`.startsWith()`, `Proxy` are going to be introduced in ES6, but they are now just prototypes and should not be used for production code. Thanks @OneKitten for the tip!

---

Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript)

Comment: Some of what you have mentioned will only be introduced with ES6, for example `String.prototype.startsWith` and proxies (though they have been experimentally implemented in Firefox). As well, the no brace function appears to be a Spidermonkey extension and not one that will be implemented by other browsers (in ES6 we'll get arrow functions).